# Numpy analogue for pandas' idxmin (index of minimum value)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, min

Is there a `numpy` analogue function or routine that does what `pandas.Series.idxmin` does, so that I don't have to import `pandas` and convert the array to pandas? `idxmin` returns the index of the minimum value in a vector.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), in numpy are not labels so it return position of minimal value.